# Font ID: Example plate from Jan Tschichold’s “The Form of the Book”

Tags: font-identification

This is an example plate illustrating the typesetting of superscripts and footnotes. The book itself is set in Monotype Van Dijck in the original German edition and Tschichold’s own Sabon in the English edition, neither of which this is.

Any help would be appreciated.

(Note especially roman and italic “J” and italic “N”.)

[image: example of superscripts and footnotes from “The Form of the Book”]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [Baskerville](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=baskerville&newwindow=1&tbm=isch) but quite which cut is not going to be easy to determine.

It's actually the J which you pointed out which allows identification. A letterpress printer once told me that the italic J could be used upside down as £ and there is [one cut](http://sdesadvtype2013s1.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/sr1-baskerville.html) which does show that.

[image: Baskerville]

[Image via [Rachel Hiller](http://sdesadvtype2013s1.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/sr1-baskerville.html)]

Comment: Thanks. Seems like StormType's revival should do; it's got the right _J_ and _N_, and a separate text weight with less contrast like the example.

Comment: The part about the upside down italic J is really interesting. Thank you.